# How to erase and merge partitions to Ubuntu start up USB drive?

Tags: usb, partitioning, merge

I have a USB start up drive with 2 partitions. How can I erase them? I cannot.

[image: b]

Comment: Have you tried using gparted?

Comment: If `gparted` fails, you can use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to erase the first mibibyte, and then use `gparted` to create a partition table and after that the partitions that you want. If there are still problems, you can analyze them, and if you are lucky solve them, according to the following link, [Analysis of the problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting Hard Disk Drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638130/formatting-hard-disk-drives)

Answer (score 5):

#### The following will completely erase the entire USB stick, so backup your data first.

1. unmount the USB stick by right-clicking on it
2. Start `gparted` and in the top right cornet, take the correct USB drive `/dev/XdY` where `X` and `Y` denoninate your USB stick.
3. Go to <kbd>device</kbd> and click <kbd>Create partition table</kbd> and take `msdos` if you want to be able to boot the USB on BIO machines and take `gpt` for all other use cases
4. Create at least one partition and format it

If any of the above steps fail,

1. Check whether the USB stick is write-protected by a switch
2. Use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to erase the first 1 Mbyte of data.

If that also fails, your USB stick has a hardware problem.  Please replace it.

Comment: Cannot be more complete than this.  @sudodus  **;-)**

Comment: +1; I think the steps of this answer can help many people with similar problems :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Merging Partitions

Rsync and Grsync, (Graphical Rsync) are tools for copying and syncing partitions.

Rsync and Grsync are available from Ubuntu Software.

[image]

The basics for using Rsync and Grsync are beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Perfect answer to merge partitions, but as OP seems to have a problem with the USB stick itself, didn't even go down that road.  **+1** for future users though adding the basics of Grsync wouldn't hurt...  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby: Now that you mention it, perhaps it is an ISO9660 problem.